# How do I solve and graph this coupled PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

$\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial v_1^2}{\partial x}=v_2 (A+\text{$\rho $B})-\text{$\rho $Bv}_1$

$\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial v_2^2}{\partial x}=v_1 (A+\text{$\rho $B})-\text{$\rho $Bv}_2$

How can I solve and graph v1 versus t and v2 versus t for a given x? Let A = 3, p = 2, B = 4. At t = 0, v1 = 2, v2 = 2. For the graph the range of t is [0,60].

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: In general, use  `NDSolve`.  Please provide your equation in Mathematica format.

Comment: Learn some Greek characters. The ones you call v and p are $\nu$ (nu) and $\rho$ (rho).

Answer (score 2):

```
A = 3;
p = 2;
B = 4;
sol = NDSolve[{
   D[v1[x, t], t] + 1/2 D[v1[x, t]^2, x] == (A + p B)*v2[x, t] - p B v1[x, t],
   D[v2[x, t], t] + 1/2 D[v2[x, t]^2, x] == (A + p B)*v1[x, t] - p B v2[x, t],
   v1[x, 0] == 2, v2[x, 0] == 2,
   v1[0, t] == 2, v2[0, t] == 2
   }, {v1, v2}, {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 60}];

Plot[Evaluate[v1[2, t] /. sol], {t, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: The boundary conditions are supposed to be periodic, so I put v1[0, t] == 2, v2[0, t] == 2,  v1[5, t] == 2, v2[5, t] == 2, and I got "NDSolve::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve." as an error.

Comment: @sam, the answer of Ivan already provides a starting point for you. In fact, this is already very kind contribution given the fact that your original  post can be improved in many aspects, notice a number of negative votes. Notice also this site is not a free homework service.